# Show/Hide product based on user role and custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I am trying to show/hide products based on user role. I have a function working perfectly for the index/search/category pages but the code I'm using to try and hide the product if you're on the individual product page. It is basically stuck in a redirect loop on any page of the website.

Basically, if you are logged in as a "super_wholesale_user" and if the product is not in the taxonomy term ID "380", it should redirect you and show you that notice.

The code I'm using is this:

```
// On single product pages, redirect to shop and display a custom notice for specific products
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wcpp_redirect_hiding_product_detail' );
function wcpp_redirect_hiding_product_detail() {

if ( ( is_user_logged_in() || ! current_user_can('super_wholesale_customer') )
&& has_term( '380', 'Role' ) && is_product() ) {
}

else {
    // Add a notice (optional)
    wc_add_notice(__("Sorry, but you are not allowed yet to see this product."), 'notice' );

    // Shop redirection url
    $redirect_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id') );
    wp_redirect($redirect_url); // Redirect to shop

    exit(); // Always exit
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. Code below for reference:

```
// On single product pages, redirect to shop and display a custom notice for specific products
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wcpp_redirect_hiding_product_detail' );
function wcpp_redirect_hiding_product_detail() {

if ( is_product() ) {

    if ( ( is_user_logged_in() || ! current_user_can('super_wholesale_customer') )
    && has_term( '380', 'Role' ) && is_product() ) {
    }
    
    else {
        // Add a notice (optional)
        wc_add_notice(__("Sorry, but you are not allowed yet to see this product."), 'notice' );

        // Shop redirection url
        $redirect_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id') );
        wp_redirect($redirect_url); // Redirect to shop

        exit(); // Always exit
    };
}

}
```